# How to use SAGA Kriging in Sextante for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

**Hello,
I tried to use SAGA (Ordinary Kriging) via SEXTANTE in QGis. The Sextante log tells me the following problem. Does anyone have a solution for my problem? By the way I'm usually a SAGA user but I wanted to change to QGis.**

Grid: [not set]
Variance: [not set]
Points: HERBST_Nuptake_Fert120
Attribute: NUPTAKE
Create Variance Grid: yes
Target Grid: user defined
Variogram Model: Spherical Model
Block Kriging: yes
Block Size: 100.000000
Logarithmic Transformation: yes
Nugget: 0.000000
Sill: 10.000000
Range: 100.000000
Linear Regression: 1.000000
Exponential Regression: 0.100000
Power Function - A: 1.000000
Power Function - B: 0.500000
Maximum Search Radius (map units): 1000.000000
Min./Max. Number of m_Points: [4.000000] - [20.000000]

error: executing module [Ordinary Kriging]

C:\Programme\Quantum GIS Lisboa>saga_cmd io_gdal 1 -GRIDS "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\user\sextante\tempdata\test.tif.sgrd" -FORMAT 1 -TYPE 0 -FILE "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\user\sextante\tempdata\test.tif"

---

##   #####

#### ###  ##

#### # ## ##  #### #

#### ##### ##    #

#   ##  ##### #

---

library path:   D:\Programme\SAGA_Beta\saga_208\modules
library name:   io_gdal
module name :   GDAL: Export Raster
author      :   O.Conrad (c) 2007

---

go...

Load grid: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\user\sextante\tempdata\test.tif.sgrd...

failed

error: Grid file could not be opened.

Comment: have you tested it with a path that does not contain spaces (the one you provided contains spaces)?

Comment: Yes I did. But when I start the Q-Gis program, an error messege pops up "Could not find the Python bindings for SAGA, which are required to run the this plugin.". Is this maybe a cause?

Comment: I have reinstalled the QGis application. I tried another SAGA-module "Clip points with polygons" but it doesnt work. This is the sextante error log:

Comment: SAGA execution console output
...
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin\gdalplugins\1.9\gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll
126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin\gdalplugins\1.9\gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll
126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.


ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin\gdalplugins\1.9\gdal_MG4Lidar.dll
126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
...

Comment: I have same problem.
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.d
ll

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you need to install Python bindings for SAGA. See information [here](https://github.com/polymeris/qgis/wiki/How-to-install-the-SAGA-Python-Bindings) and more specific for Windows - [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/saga-gis/wiki/Compiling%20SAGA%20Python%20Bindings%20on%20Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified the path to your SAGA folder in Sextante options and configuration? 
What OS are you using?
How did you install QGIS? Did you use the osgeo4w installer?

As an aside, I must say that ECW_JP2ECW.dll turns up regularly as a problem in QGIS....

Comment: Yes i have checked the path. I'm using Windows xp. I have installed the program via the common install (*.exe) file.